# PKWARE ZIP Central Directory Encryption

Tags: encryption, zip, pkware

In [ZIP File Format Specification v6.3.5](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm/blob/master/src/test/resources/ZIP%20File%20Format%20Specification%20v6.3.5.txt) there is **7.3 Single Password - Central Directory Encryption**.

It seems that only on application support this feature [SecureZip by PKWARE](https://www.pkware.com/zip-reader). Does anyone know how exactly this feature is implemented? I am looking for any working sources and language of this feature; I am planning to add this feature to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is already aware, but for others who find this question in the future...

To my knowledge, there are no open source implementations.

The central directory encryption functionality is patented. Contact zipformat@pkware.com with legal questions or to obtain a license.

Source: I'm an engineer at PKWARE